# App Check PlayIntegrity Not Working - Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-app-check, safetynet, google-play-integrity-api

I have implemented App Check for my application , I have registered Sha256s,activated appcheck in console,initialized it buy it doesnt work with play Integrity !! I always get " Detected invalid AppCheck token. Reconnecting (0 attempts remaining) Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Invalid appcheck token" ,
But with safetynet it works well however as we know it will be deprecated

My code:

initialize app check
[image]

as you can see if I change play integrity by safetynet it works well ,i can access to my db,but safe net will stop working in about one year

I have already read all posts related to this problem on this web ,but i havent been able to find a solution Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share more information about the dependencies? Also, have you tried deleting the app from the device and then test it again?

Comment: @Gerardo I tried and got the same error

Comment: No solution found

Comment: _Firebaser here._ Thank you for bringing this to our attention. Please file an issue at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues, and include details you are comfortable sharing. You can also file a support ticket directly with [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) without publicizing those details.