# How can I still get the email address when I enabled skip login on the second launch of the app in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I enabled the skip login, wherein I am not able to get the email of the account I was logged in to.

How can I still get the email if skip login is enabled in the second launch of the app?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "f skip login is enabled"? The relevant code, or a screenshot of the relevant UI, would probably help for that.

Comment: On first launch you will locally save login credentials of user, And at second time you will have that data and able to fetch user information. Check SharedPrefrences https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences  for saving data locally. Hope it helps

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thank you for responding, I have solved the problem by adding sharedpreferences

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase authentication state persists across application restarts. So there is no need to save the email address locally in order to use it again when you restart the application. As soon as you create an instance of the [FirebaseAuth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth) class, you can call [getCurrentUser()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#getCurrentUser()) which:

> Returns the currently signed-in FirebaseUser or null if there is none.

As you can see, the type object that is returned is [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser). If this object is null it means that your user is not logged in, otherwise, you can call [FirebaseUser#getEmail()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#getEmail()). In this way, you can always get the email address from this object, without the need to perform any other operations.

If you want to track the auth state, then I recommend you check my answer from the following post:

- [One time login in app - FirebaseAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885891/one-time-login-in-app-firebaseauth)

If you want to see a real example, please check this [resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885891/one-time-login-in-app-firebaseauth), with the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAuthentication).

Comment: Hey Jason. Did my answer help you? Can I help you with other information?

Answer (score 0):

While launching the app first time, after login you can save the username and email in Shared Preference and on second time launch you can fetch it. First initialize App Preference using method

```
AppPreferences.INSTANCE.initAppPreferences(ActivityName.this);
```

Then set userName and use it.

Code is shared below

```
public enum AppPreferences {
INSTANCE;
private static final String SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME = "AppName";
private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
private Editor mEditor;


public void initAppPreferences(Context context) {
    mPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mEditor = mPreferences.edit();
}

public String getUserName() {
    return mPreferences.getString(SharedPreferencesKeys.user_name.toString(), "");
}

public void setUserName(String value) {
    mEditor.putString(SharedPreferencesKeys.user_name.toString(), value);
    mEditor.commit();
}
}
```